# Is my mini text correct? How can I write it better?

Tags: writing-critique

我的名字是Leandro, 我在学习汉语三年。这是一号的文本，这是不好。 我要会说汉语因为我要走工作自中国.

What i tried to write:

My name is Leandro, I've been studying Chinese for 3 years. This is my first text, it isn't good. I want to speak Chinese so I can work in China.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My name is Leandro, - 我的名字是Leandro*

Looks good

> *I've been studying Chinese for 3 years - 我在学习汉语三年*

**我己学习了汉语三年**

- I've been = 我己經 (not '我在学' - 'I am learning')

> *This is my first (Chinese) writing, - 这是一号的文本*

**这是我的第一次中文写作**

- my = 我的
- text = writing = 写作

> *it isn't good. - 这是不好。*

**不是很流利**

- subject 'it' can be omitted
- 流利 = fluent ("not good" is too general)

> *I want to (learn) to speak Chinese so I can work in China. - 我要会说汉语，因为我要走工作自中国*

**我想学说汉语，这样我就能在中国工了**

- want to = 想 (not 要)
- so = 这样 (not 因为)
- 自 is a typo of 在
- 走 is a typo of 就
- In Chinese grammar, it is 就能在中国工作, not 就能工作在中国

Answer (score 3):

我的名字是Leandro, 我已經学了三年的汉语 (I've studied Chinese for 3 years)。 这是我第一次用汉语書寫 (This is my first time writing using Chinese)，寫的不是很好 (it isn't very good/readable)。 我必需學会说汉语是因为我的工作是在中国 (The reason I must learn to speak Chinese is that my job is in China).

In the last sentence, you may attach any reason that is corresponding to the reasoning - 我必需學会说汉语是因为...

- 我希望留在中國工作. (I wish to stay and work in China)
- 工作需要. (required by work)

Answer (score 1):

> 我的名字是Leandro,

no problem

> 我在学习汉语三年。

我（已经）学习了三年汉语。 I've been studying Chinese for 3 years.

“了” Used after a verb or adjective to indicate completion

> 这是一号的文本，这是不好。

这是我第一次写作，写得不好。
一号的文本 means “Text No. 1”，“First time writing” is “第一次写作”

“得” Used after a verb or adjective to connect a complement that expresses degree or result.

> 我要会说汉语因为我要走工作自中国.

我想（学习）说汉语以便在中国工作。

. ×  。 √

“want to” is 想 or 想要，not 要

“so” = “以便” or “为了” Expressing purpose, not cause and effect